# arrange div elements in square using javascript and maths

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

I n number of divs which are arranged in a circle using JavaScript. Right now I set the dimension of each div to `40×40`. Below is what I am able to achieve so far. This is how I find X & Y of each div.

```js
x = 100 * Math.cos(angle) + hCenter;
y = 100 * Math.sin(angle) + vCenter;
```

where hCenter & vCenter are center point of the screen

[image: Circles]

1. When there are many circles they start overlapping each other. How
   can I find the height & width of each div so that they fit in circle
   with a little space between each other.
2. How can I arrange the same circles in the square. Means animate from
   circle to square. How to find new X,Y position of each div.

Comment: In which square? How do you want to arrange them therein? What do you mean by "new position", do you refer to the animation? What paths should the cirles take in the animation?

Comment: the screen itself is the square. And i want the elements to be arranged at the edges. So how should i move each circle so that all circles are in square form. By animation i mean just jQuery animation to move circles from current position to the new position i.e. in square form. Its like stretching this circle to the square

Comment: Stretching so that they are equidistant, or stretching so that they maintain their angle?

Comment: so that they maintain their angle

Answer (score 1):

> How can I find the height & width of each div so that they fit in circle with a little space between each other.

The width and height of each circle are the same as its diameter, which (plus the little splace) is equivalent to the length of the sides of the polygon formed by their positions. You know the size ("diameter") of the large square/circle in which the are arranged, so you can easily compute the [length of the sides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon#Circumradius) from that and the number of items. Then subtract a small constant or factor, and you've got your result.

> How to find new X,Y position of each div so that they are arranged in a square?

Compute from the angle on which side of the square they will sit. You've got your first coordinate. Then, use `sin`/`cos` to compute the position on that side.

```
var dir = Math.round(angle / Math.PI * 2) % 4,
    dis = dir<2 ? 100 : -100;
if (dir % 2 == 0) {
    x = hCenter + dis;
    y = vCenter + dis * Math.tan(angle);
} else {
    x = hCenter + dis / Math.tan(angle);
    y = vCenter + dis;
}
```

Comment: hey bro, i think you did not understand my first point of finding height & width. Right now i have 15 circles arranged in a circular area. If i add one more circle then i have to reduce the size of each circle so that the new one fits the circular figure. so reduce to what size is my question?

Comment: No, that's just the question I did answer. You calculate the sizes of the circles by calculating the side length of the regular polygon.

Comment: hey what if i need to maintain the distance as well ? sorry for repeated question but my maths is weak